# Writing at index 0 in contenteditable inline element

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, rangy

I've a contenteditable `<p>` element which contains text, inside this `<p>`element there is one inline element which is a `<span>`
contenteditable won't allow me to write at index 0 in the `<span>`

I made an fiddle to demo the problem:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x4xdekg/9/)

Now open the browsers console and then try to type anything at index 0 in the inline `<span>`. As you can see the text input will not be placed at index 0 but instead at the last index of the first text node.

I've tried to change this behaviour with `rangy.js`.
The idea was to check if the carret where placed at the last index in the first text node, then on right arrow pressed I would place the carret to index 0 in the second node. But the problem persisted.

```
      //rangy try without the if-statement.       
      var nodes = $el[1].childNodes, index = 0;
      var range = rangy.createRange();
      //Setting the start at node 2 index 0.
      range.setStart(nodes[1], index);
      range.collapse(true);
      var sel = rangy.getSelection();
      sel.setSingleRange(range);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation (browser) specific behaviour.

Rerence: http://www.w3.org/community/editing/wiki/ContentEditable#Collapsed_selections_.28carets.29

> - Given a dom with multiple dom positions for the same visible positions, UA's currently vary in which position is considered the
>     typeable position. Example: given `foo<b>bar</b>baz`
>
>   - With the cursor between foo and bar, insertions happen:
>
>     - IE: Click, outside B. Arrows, inside.
>     - FF: Click, outside. Arrow from inside the tag, inside. Arrow from outside the tag, outside.
>     - Chrome: Always out.

As you can see the behaviour is different in different browsers. While in IE and FF you can click inside your `span` and use arrow key to move to the first position, Chrome will always put the cursor outside of your `span`. Also, with FF you can only move using arrow key from inside of the `span`, if moving from outside the cursor shall remain outside.

Comment: Thanks. Well I do understand the problem. The question is if there is a workaround for the default browser behaviours.

Comment: @JonathanAndersson: No, because there is no way to tell apart the intention of the user, whether they actually wanted to insert a character at the start of tag or at the end of previous textnode.